# After using dismissViewController on a modal view, the intended view pushes multiple times

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**This is a problem I can't seem to find any solution for online.**

I have the following storyboard:

[image]

The rows in the initial table view have a push segue to the view that you can see above the other views.

Now when I press the bar button in the initial table view, it performs a modal segue to a new navigation controller (the one in the middle) where you can create an object.

in the selectFriends view at the far right, when you press on done it runs this code:

```
self.dismissViewController(true, completion: nil)
```

then it brings me back to the initial table view *which is what I want.*

**Here's where it gets weird**

if I dismiss the modal navigation controller from the first view in it, it works fine

however, when I dismiss the modal navigation controller from the selectFriends view, it goes back to the initial table view,

**Then runs the goToChat segue as many times in a row as it has been performed before presenting the modal view.**

It doesn't even run the didSelectRowAtIndexPath code.

My guess is that it has to do with some mapping or storing of views and segues in the initial navigation controller.

The initial table view has this for didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
    // finds user item to pass to UserProfileView
    print("row selected")

    if self.resultSearchController.active {

        self.selectedItem = self.filteredItemsList[indexPath.row]

    } else {

        self.selectedItem = self.itemsList[indexPath.row]


    }

    self.ref.child("users/\(self.currentUser!.uid)").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in

        self.currentUserItem = UserItem(snapshot: snapshot)
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goToChat", sender: nil)

    })


}
```

Please let me know if you have a solution.

Best wishes,
Khaled

Comment: It looks like the problem is your `observeEventType` method. What is that? I've never seen anything like it.

Comment: It's a firebase data recall that fires everytime the database is changed... So when the object is created, it runs regardless of selection. YOU ARE ABSOLUTELY CORRECT! Thanks for bringing my attention to this.

Comment: Right, so my guess is, by calling `observeEventType` you've "registered" the observer and so now it just fires again because it is still observing... That's why the code doesn't need to run again; the "block" has been retained, so it runs by itself now.

Comment: It does exactly that. Thanks!

Comment: You should add the firebase tag to your question, and you should answer your own question! Perfectly legal (encouraged, in fact). Might help others.

Answer (score 0):

This was kind of embarrassing. I was actually diving into the UIKit code to see the presentViewController and performSegueWithIdentifier function's code hoping to find my answer.

But as Matt pointed out in the comments, the `observeEventType` function DID look out of place. Looking closer, I realised my mistake.

Everytime I selected a table row, it registered a new event listener for changes in the database, so once a new item is created, it launches the code inside (including the segue) the amount of times that a listener has been registered.

I fixed it like this:

```
// This is a Firebase "user object" that carries the current user's ID

let currentUser = FIRAuth.auth().currentUser 

// Now we set the listener in the viewDidLoad to simply update the currentUserItem
and not perform any segue or code that we only need to run once.

override func viewDidLoad() {

    self.ref.child("users/\(self.currentUser.uid)").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in

    self.currentUserItem = UserItem(snapshot: snapshot)

    })

}
```

Now in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method we only get the selectedItem at that row and run the segue. ONCE.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    // finds item in respective row to enter chat
    if self.resultSearchController.active {

        self.selectedItem = self.filteredItemsList[indexPath.row]

    } else {

        self.selectedItem = self.ItemsList[indexPath.row]


    }

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goToChat", sender: nil)

}
```

Again, thanks Matt!